# The lines that I draw get removed when another line is drawn

Tags: java, swing, awt

The lines that I draw get removed when another line is drawn. I am using mouse event to draw lines but when ever i draw the second line the first one get removed. I believe it has something to do with my points which keep changing the location of the coordinates where i want to draw the line as my click keep changing the points but i am not sure that's the reason; please help thanks in advance

```
public class DrawOnComponent

{

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

JFrame f = new JFrame("Draw a Red Line");

f.setSize(300, 300);

f.setLocation(300, 300);

f.setResizable(false);

JPanel p = new JPanel() {

    Point pointStart = null;

    Point pointEnd   = null;

    {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                pointStart = e.getPoint();

            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                pointStart = null;
            }
        });
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                pointEnd = e.getPoint();
            }

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                pointEnd = e.getPoint();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        if (pointStart != null) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawLine(pointStart.x, pointStart.y, pointEnd.x, pointEnd.y);
        }
    }
};
f.add(p);
f.setVisible(true); 

} }
```

Comment: Please post text that goes into the details of your question. Don't just post a vague title and nothing but code -- **explain** the problem so that we can well understand it.

Comment: Tell us: 1) what you're trying to achieve, 2) what your code currently does, 3) what it doesn't do that you expect it should do, 4) any and all error messages, 5) what it does that you don't expect it to do -- in other words, put just a little effort into explaining the details. Again, the key to getting a good answer is to help folks understand the problem. Makes sense, right?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: Another edit and **still** no code formatting? Lift your game..

Comment: @AndrewThompson: he is now continually defacing his own question.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post.

Answer (score 3):

If you want lines to persist, then you need to draw all the lines that need to be seen. This is often done in one of two ways:

- Create an ArrayList of something to hold line data, such as an `ArrayList<Line2D>`, add to it when you want to add a new line, and then in paintComponent, iterate through the list drawing each line.
- Or drawing each line to a BufferedImage, and drawing the BufferedImage in paintComponent using `Graphics#drawImage(...)`.

For example -- using a BufferedImage, we'd get the Graphics object from the BufferedImage, draw onto the image using it, dispose of the object, and then call `repaint()` to ask the GUI to repaint itself. The JPanel's paintComponent method would draw the image:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawLines extends JPanel {
    // size of things
    private static final int BI_W = 600;
    private static final int BI_H = BI_W;
    private static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.WHITE;

    // properties of the temporary and permanent lines
    private static final Color LINE_COLOR = new Color(200, 200, 255);
    public static final Color SAVED_LINES_COLOR = Color.BLUE;
    public static final Stroke SAVED_LINES_STROKE = new BasicStroke(5f);

    // image to hold permanent lines
    private BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(BI_W, BI_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // of true, draw temporary line
    private boolean drawTempLine = false;
    private int x1 = 0;
    private int y1 = 0;
    private int x2 = 0;
    private int y2 = 0;

    public DrawLines() {
        setBackground(BACKGROUND_COLOR);

        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        addMouseListener(myMouse);
        addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);

        if (drawTempLine) {
            g.setColor(LINE_COLOR);
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        int w = img.getWidth();
        int h = img.getHeight();
        return new Dimension(w, h);
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            x1 = e.getX();
            y1 = e.getY();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            x2 = e.getX();
            y2 = e.getY();
            drawTempLine = true;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            x2 = e.getX();
            y2 = e.getY();

            // draw to buffered image with its graphics object
            Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
            // for smoother drawing
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            // set the color and thickness of the saved line
            g2.setColor(SAVED_LINES_COLOR);
            g2.setStroke(SAVED_LINES_STROKE);

            // draw the saved line
            g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

            // we're done with this Graphics object -- dispose of it
            g2.dispose();

            // tell gui not to draw the temporary drawing line
            drawTempLine = false;

            // ask GUI to repaint itself
            repaint();
        }

    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        DrawLines mainPanel = new DrawLines();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw Lines");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know how to use BufferedImage and i tried ArrayList it didnt work.

Comment: @xenon: I don't see an ArrayList attempt in your question's code. If you've tried it and it doesn't work, please show the attempt.

Comment: i just placed a part of my code where i believe the error is

Comment: @xenon: your code is missing the "bottom" part, and you will want to learn to format your code correctly as Andrew and I have been trying to fix for you. If formatted well, we can read it. Please post the rest of the code.

Comment: sorry about that of let me try to put the whole code

Comment: sorry i am new to this site and dont know how to place code

Comment: *"dont know how to place code"* Which is why I explained how to do it 6 minutes before the latest edit. :-/

Comment: @xenon: when you edit your question, there's a question mark in the upper right corner, click on it and go into advanced help. This will help you learn how to edit your question and your code.

Comment: @xenon: see example above that uses a BufferedImage.

Comment: how can i implement it to my code i am using points. i am confused working on this program from last whole week lol

Comment: As far as your code, I'm still having trouble reading it as it is formatted in a difficult way. Please try to fix -- try to emulate my code above. All code in the same block should be indented the exactly same amount, usually 4 spaces. Avoid too much white space -- lines that should be together should be together without too much blank lines. Blank lines belong between methods and major sections, and that's it.

Comment: @xenon: I posted a complete example program that I just now created to try to help you, and you're now posting nonsense. Please stop wasting our time, and post serious code.

Comment: @xenon: I've just now rolled back your post to at least more reasonable code.

Comment: hey i dont want anyone to copy my program thats why i did that no hard feelings thanks for the help again

Comment: @xenon: trust me, no one will copy your code, but more importantly, *your* question on this site is not really yours at all, but rather belongs to the community. If you sabotage your question after asking it, you render it useless for future visitors who come searching for solutions to similar problems. So please either improve it or at least leave it as is.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/).

It has working examples of the two common ways to do incremental painting:

1. paint from a List of objects
2. draw on a BufferedImage.

Which approach you use depends on your exact requirement.

Comment: @xenon, Then you didn't follow either of the examples I provided. Did you download both of the examples and test them out? Did you modify the examples to draw a line instead of a Rectangle?

Comment: I tried it has too many methods(no offense) and i am not able to evaluate where should i look for solution to my problem. But yes that exactly what i want my lines to function

Comment: You have been given working code by me and Hovercraft. We are not here to write the code for you, only point you in the right direction. It is up to you to understand it and customize it. Rarely will you ever find code that does exactly what you want, so you need to learn how to modify code you find. `i am not able to evaluate where should i look for solution to my problem` - I suggested you start by modifying the code to draw a line instead of a Rectangle. Then once you get that working you can either add more logic to that code or fix your code.

Comment: thanks for the help and i didn't ask you to write my code

Comment: @xenon, the answer that helped you solve your problem should be "accepted" by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.